# PayPal: integrating third party shopping cart with encrypted website payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using my own custom shopping cart and integrating it with paypal. Now I wish to encrypt the parameters appearing on the form but have been unable to do so using the tutorial here: https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmacole/encrypting-your-buttons-through-paypal-api-php-using-soap . The issue is, that I'm unable to pass the _cart parameter to "cmd" to make PayPal use my shopping cart values. I may not be able to use the openSSL solution for encrypted website payment standard.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the cart upload method or simply create an add to cart button that adds one item to the cart at a time?  The button manager API's do not suport the cart upload method if you are trying to do this.  If you are just trying to create an add to cart button can you provide what you are sending over in your API request and what you are getting back?